# What is the smallest sensible transaction?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees

While the smallest fraction of bitcoins currently implemented is the Satoshi (10<sup>-8</sup> BTC or 10 nBTC (nano-bitcoins)), due to transaction fees there seems to be a minimum amount of BTC to be spent that is larger than one Satoshi. What is currently the smallest amount of BTC one can spend at comparably little to no fees. i.e. what is currently the smallest sensible unit of microtransactions?

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that the most smallest and sensible transaction is at least 0.0001

**HOWEVER NOTE:** If you want a confirmation in 10 or 20 minutes, you will need to post a minimum transfer fee of 0.0001

**So technically** If you want to transfer 0.0001 to a account you will need at least 0.0002

If you want to transfer a bigger amount, the transaction fee will not need to be changed
e.g. If you want to transfer X amount to a account you will need at least X amount + 0.0001

I have tried to transfer 0.00005593 with no transaction fee, and there is still no confirmations: https://blockchain.info/tx/15ee5484920eed92457643a1709629d8ff579b15fc805b0060a9cf0efdcbb8ed

**Transfer More faster = Pay a Higher transfer fee**

Just to note: transfer fee same as Miners Fee same as transaction fee

Comment: Hi Astad, welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Please don't solicit donations for your answers; the reputation system is all the currency we need here.

Comment: @Astad Greg is fully correct, the Bitcoin.SE is not for collecting tips.

Comment: You're allowed to put your address in the profile, and you can put an address into an answer if it is relevant. A tipping address will **never** be relevant, and we reward users with up votes.